# C++ Stack using a doubly linked list

Tags: c++, list, stack

I'm trying to implement a stack using a doubly linked list. I know that the functions for my stack class (push, pop) should contain calls to member functions of my doubly linked list class, but I'm having trouble actually implementing that.

dlist.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "dlist.hpp"

using namespace std;

void dlist::appendNodeFront(int shares, float pps){
  Node *n = new Node(shares, pps);
  if(front == NULL){
    front = n;
    back = n;
  }
  else {
    front->prev = n;
    n->next = front;
    front = n;
  }
}

void dlist::appendNodeBack(int shares, float pps){
  Node *n = new Node(shares, pps);
  if(back == NULL){
    front = n;
    back = n;
  }
  else {
    back->next = n;
    n->prev = back;
    back = n;
  }
}

void dlist::display(){
  Node  *temp = front;
  cout << "List contents: ";
  while(temp != NULL){
    cout << temp->value << " ";
    temp = temp->next;
  }
  cout << endl;
}

void dlist::display_reverse(){
  Node *temp = back;
  cout << "List contents in reverse: ";
  while(temp != NULL){
    cout << temp->value << " ";
    temp = temp->prev;
  }
  cout << endl;
}

void dlist::destroyList(){
  Node *T = back;
  while(T != NULL){
    Node *T2 = T;
    T = T->prev;
    delete T2;
  }
  front = NULL;
  back = NULL;
}
```

stack.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "stack.hpp"

using namespace std;

stack::stack(){
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < 1500; i++){
    shares[i] = 0;
    pps[i] = 0;
  }
  first = 0;
}

void stack::push(int num, float price){
  if(first ==(1500-1)){
    cout << "Stack is full" << endl;
    return;
  }
  first++;
  shares[first] = num;
  pps[first] = price;

  return;
}

void stack::pop(int *num, float *price){
  if(first == -1){
    cout << "Stack is empty" << endl;
    return;
  }

  num = &shares[first];
  price = &pps[first];

  cout << shares[first] << endl;
  cout << pps[first] << endl;
  shares[first] = 0;
  pps[first] = 0;
  first--;
  return;
}
```

Should the push function in stack basically be a call to `appendNodeFront()` or `appendNodeback()`? Any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Push should append an element at the end of the stack, so appendNodeback() is the right function to call. For the pop operation you need to remove the last element inserted into the stack, so will have to implement a removeLastNode() function.

Comment: It seems that these functions have mixed responsibilities. E.g., both create node and append it somewhere. Things can be simpler when you separate responsibilities. Hey, that concept even has [its own Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)! Whoa.

Comment: Two scenarios: push from the head/pop from the head or push from the tail/pop from the tail. The point is that the the last element inserted should be the first element removed (LIFO).

Comment: Why not use [`std::stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack), or at least [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)?

Comment: You don't need doubly-linked list for stack. Singly-linked list would suffice. Head of list becomes top of the stack. In case you want double-linked list, it doesn't matter which end you choose - you just have to make sure you `push()` and `pop()` from the same end.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf hey, but creating node involves allocating memory for it and assigning some values to it - that's mixed responsibilities! Appending somewhere involves setting node pointers and updating list head/tail pointers. That's mixed responsibilities! I think you take SRP too far.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a stack class, then use linked list class as its container. In a linked list class there is virtually no limit to the number of items, so you add artificial limit to make it work like a stack. In a linked list, items can be added/removed anywhere in the list, you can limit add/remove the tail node only to make it work like stack. The example below demonstrate the usage.

Node that this is purely a programming exercise. Stack is relatively primitive compared to Doubly-linked list. Encapsulating a linked-list inside stack has no advantage. Also note, I declared all members as `public` for the sake of simplifying the problem, you may want to change some members to `protected`/`private`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;

class Node
{
public:
    Node *prev;
    Node *next;
    int shares;
    float pps;
    Node(int vshares, float vpps)
    {
        shares = vshares;
        pps = vpps;
        prev = next = nullptr;
    }
};

class dlist
{
public:
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;

    dlist()
    {
        head = tail = nullptr;
    }
    ~dlist()
    {
        destroy();
    }

    void push_back(int shares, float pps) 
    {
        Node *node = new Node(shares, pps);
        if (head == NULL) 
        {
            head = tail = node;
        }
        else 
        {
            tail->next = node;
            node->prev = tail;
            tail = node;
        }
    }

    void destroy() 
    {
        Node *walk = head;
        while (walk) 
        {
            Node *node = walk;
            walk = walk->next;
            delete node;
        }
        head = tail = nullptr;
    }
};

class stack
{
public:
    int maxsize;
    int count;
    dlist list;
    stack(int size)
    {
        count = 0;
        maxsize = size;
    }

    void push(int num, float price)
    {
        if (count < maxsize)
        {
            list.push_back(num, price);
            count++;
        }
    }

    void pop()
    {
        Node *tail = list.tail;
        if (!tail)
        {
            //already empty
            return;
        }

        if (tail == list.head)
        {
            //only one element in the list
            delete tail;
            list.head = list.tail = nullptr;
            count--;
        }
        else
        {
            Node *temp = list.tail->prev;
            delete list.tail;
            list.tail = temp;
            list.tail->next = nullptr;
            count--;
        }
    }

    void display()
    {
        Node  *walk = list.head;
        while (walk)
        {
            cout << "(" << walk->shares << "," << walk->pps << ") ";
            walk = walk->next;
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    stack s(3);
    s.push(101, 0.25f);
    s.push(102, 0.25f);
    s.push(103, 0.25f);
    s.push(104, 0.25f);
    s.display();
    s.pop();
    s.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "In a linked list class there is virtually no limit to the number of items, so you add artificial limit to make it work like a stack" - there's no requirement that stack have limit whereas list doesn't.